# What does "brought up from the city" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english, adverbs

This is a part of a script for the movie "Annie Hall" with Woody Allen and Diane Keaton:

> ALVY
>
> M'm, wait, I got a great idea.
> (He gets up and goes over to the
> closet, taking out a light bulb.
> He goes back to the bed and turns
> out the lamp on the night table).
> Hang in there for a second.  I got a  little-little artifact.  A little erotic artifact, that-that I **brought up from the city**, which I think, uh, is gonna be perfect.

In one of the previous scenes in the movie, Alvie reveals that he lives uptown. Annie Hall is filmed in New York which has it's city center located downtown.(hence the term downtown meaning city center in AE).
Does this mean that when Alvie talks about the erotic artefact that he "brought up from the city" he means that he "brought it from city which is located south and took it home which is located north"?

**"up" adv**

b. to a more northerly place: up to Scotland.(Collins English Dictionary)

Comment: Downtown=city centre/center (business district). Uptown=residential area. In New York and other cities, you go up (or bring something up) from downtown (the city) to uptown.

Comment: But it's an area where local usage can vary. From Scotland and Northern England some people may go "down to London", but from most of England they go "up to London", even from the North. And I know people in Glasgow and Edinburgh who say "go through" (without an object) to mean "go to the other one of the two cities".

Comment: @ColinFine - *"they go "up to London", even from the North"* Nope, not where I come from, Yorkshire. South is always 'down'. It might be dialectical use in some areas, but I don't think you can generalise, especially on one so well-known as the 'down south, up north' structure in the UK. To either confuse or consolidate, idk… where I grew up the town centre was 'down' for everyone, literally. It was in a valley surrounded by hills.

Comment: @Tetsujin: I live in Yorkshire too. On reflection, I think you're right. When I lived in Cambridge, it was always "up to London" (even though that was Southward), but here, you hear "down to London" more. I wonder where the cutoff is, where map-direction  takes over from status.

Comment: @ColinFine - I might need to ask my partner, she's a Southerner;) We live in London these days. She doesn't have the faintest idea where 'geography' starts, whether Cambridge, Brighton or Aberdeen would be up or down. Perhaps we Northerners have a stronger sense of geographical 'identity'. {/me walks off into the sunset, with echoes of Mel Gibson's "ye'll nivur tak oor freedom" making him shudder…}

Comment: 'Appen. Ah've bin in Yorkshire thirty yeer now - will it tek another thirty while ah get to be proper Yorkshire, does tha think?

Comment: @ColinFine - tha'll never mek it lad ;)) Oi've been in Landen, the same, firty years. Moi Mockeys' cammin on foine, nah… innit ;))

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember where they are during that scene but can think of five possibilities:

1. They are in northern Manhattan, for example in Alvy's uptown apartment. He might call the lower parts of Manhattan "the city", especially if he lives in the far north of the island. However, "the city" usually includes all of Manhattan, so this would be a bit unusual.
2. They are north of NYC, e.g. in Westchester or the Catskills.
3. They are in the Bronx, which is north of Manhattan. (Even though NYC includes five boroughs, it is common for "the city" to mean Manhattan only.)
4. The characters could literally be "up" from the city, e.g. in the Poconos (a mountain range to the west of NYC).
5. New Yorkers aren't always strict about directions, so they might even be in the Hamptons, for example. This use of "up" would be uncommon but by no means unheard of.